# Confluence jars not loaded/found in my plugin

Tags: spring, classloader, confluence

I am trying to get our onfluence plugin to run under Confluence 5.10.5.
The plugin needs some dependencies which are in the confluence/WEB-INF/lib.
I have defined them as provided in my pom.xml.

        ......
        
            org.hsqldb
            hsqldb
            2.3.4
            provided

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>.org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When executing the plugin I get the error

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'getDialects' in  class info.novatec.testit.livingdoc.confluence.actions.server.InstallationAction threw exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5Dialect at templates/livingdoc/configuration/installation/configurationDbmsEdit.vm[line 20, column 50]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:237)
....
...
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect not found by
info.novatec.testit.livingdoc.confluence.plugin [250]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
```

If I add the needed packages to the atlassia-plugin.xml
org.hibernate.dialect.*;resolution:="mandatory"
I get the following error when the plugin is loaded at confluence startup

`org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle livingdoc.confluence.plugin [250]: Unable to resolve 250.0: missing requirement [250.0] osgi.wiring. package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.hibernate.dialect)`

What do I need to do in order to get the confluence jars loaded for my plugin classpath?

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone is having the same problem ..
I have learned that hibernate is not exposed for import by confluence.
So I had to add it as wel as hibernate-envers as dependency.